# Best way to propagate variables from QWizard to the pages

Tags: qt

Iam looking for a good and easy way to propagate a variable, in my case a string from QWizard on to the pages. I have tried to use fields but without registering it this won't work.

So on the third page of my wizard I need a path to a folder where some data can be found, this is used to init a QFileDialog. This QString is not directly coupled to a QWidget. So I can not call registerField on it.

pseudo code:

```
// setup wizard:
    QMyWizard wiz;
    QString s = "c:\\";
    wiz.SetFolder(s);
```

I can of course in the Wizard SetFolder function access the page by looking it up and casting but I find this quite ugly. So Is there a good solution to pass on global variable without registering to widgets?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood correctly your issue, anyway you could create an intermediate class called e.g. SharedData for the project for storing/reading app global stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.. I did not find handy functionality in the wizard code itself. Now I am using the ability of any derived class from QObject to hold properties in a map from string to QVariant. In the wizard pages you can acces the properties of the parent now.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#setProperty